# Fallback for "std::ostream" and "<<" operator using SFINAE and templates in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae, type-traits

I'm using Catch2 with `TEST_CASE` blocks from within I sometimes declare local temporary `struct` for convenience. These `struct` sometimes needs to be displayed, and to do so Catch2 suggests to implement the `<<` operator with `std::ostream`. Unfortunately, this becomes quite complicated to implement with local-only `struct` because such operator can't be defined inline nor in the `TEST_CASE` block.

I thought of a possible solution which would be to define a template for `<<` which would call `toString()` instead if that method exists:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& obj) -> decltype(obj.toString(), void(), out)
{
    out << obj.toString();
    return out;
}

struct A {
    std::string toString() const {
      return "A";
    }
};


int main() {
    std::cout << A() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a few questions:

- Is the `decltype` trick modern C++ or can we achieve the same using `<type_traits>` instead?
- Is there a way to require for the `toString()` returned value to be a `std::string` and thus disable the template substitution otherwise?
- Is it guaranteed that a class with a concrete implementation of `operator<<` will be prioritized over the template if it exists?

Also, I find this solution to be quite fragile (I get errors when compiling my overall project although this simple snippet works), and I think it can lead to errors because of its implicit nature. Unrelated classes may define `toString()` method without expecting it to be used in `<<` template substitution.

I thought it might be cleaner to do this explicitly using a base class and then SFINAE:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct WithToString {};

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<WithToString, T>>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& obj)
{
    out << obj.toString();
    return out;
}

struct A : public WithToString {
    std::string toString() const {
      return "A";
    }
};


int main() {
    std::cout << A() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The downside of this solution is that I can't define `toString()` as a `virtual` method in the base class otherwise it prevents aggregate initialization (which is super-useful for my test cases). Consequently, `WithToString` is just an empty `struct` which serves as a "marker" for `std::enable_if`. It does not bring any useful information by itself, and it requires documentation to be properly understood and used.

What are your thoughts on this second solution? Can this be improved somehow?

I'm targeting C++17 so I can't use `<concepts>` yet unfortunately. Also I would like to avoid using the `<experimental>` header (although I know it contains useful stuff for C++17).

Comment: Neat!  I learned something today, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of both methods as "`operator<<` on all types with some property".

The first property is "has a `toString()`" method (and will work in C++11 even. This is still SFINAE, in this case the substitutions are in the return type). You can make it check that `toString()` returns a `std::string` with a different style of SFINAE:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<const T&>().toString())>, std::string>,
int> = 0>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& obj)
{
    out << obj.toString();
    return out;
}
```

And a non-template `operator<<` will always be chosen before this template. A more "specialized" template will also be chosen before this one. The rules for overload resolution are a bit complex, but they can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function

The second property is "derives from `WithToString`". As you guessed, this one is more "explicit", and it is harder to accidentally/unexpectedly use the `operator<<`.

You can actually define the operator inline, with a friend function:

```cpp
struct A {
    std::string toString() const {
      return "A";
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
        return os << a.toString();
    }
};
```

And you could also have this friend declaration in `WithToString`, making it a self-documenting [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)

```cpp
template<typename T>  // (crtp class)
struct OutputFromToStringMixin {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj) {
        return os << obj.toString();
    }
};

struct A : OutputFromToStringMixin<A> {
    std::string toString() const {
      return "A";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I think I can't use `friend` in my case due to "friend function cannot be defined in a local class" error (when `struct` is locally defined in a function for example). I didn't think about using CRTP, that seems to be a very good idea for self-documentating a Mixin without introducing `virtual` method. Unfortunately, I discovered having a base class clutters the aggregate initialization by requiring empty braces before attributes (`A a{{}, "some attribute"};`). I'll probably opt for the improved SFINAE you shared with a very specific method name to avoid conflicts.